# How do I fix a flickering (blinking) menu screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, flicker

I have added a GIF where you can see that when I click on favourite (heart) menu it loads smoothly and doesn't flick but when I click on side menu it flicks

[image]

I am working on an app and I am trying to resolve an issue, there is a screen whenever I click it, it flicks or blinks, it kind of refreshes. All the content it contain refresh, like if I click it I feel like I come on that screen then the items come there later on, it happens in few frictions of seconds but it is too annoying. I tried everything but still.
I tried to slow down the animation globally by using time dilation but it is still happening.

```
const String logo = "assets/profile/images/stadia_logo.svg";

class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfileScreenState createState() => _ProfileScreenState();
}

class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    final StorageService ref = StorageService();
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final logoHeight = screenHeight * 0.4;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: ref.getProfileUrl(user.uid),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> url) {
            if (url.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Loading(
                size: 20,
              );
            }
            if (url.hasData) {
              return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                  stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Loading(
                        size: 15,
                      );
                    }

                    if (snapshot.data == null) {
                      return Loading(
                        size: 15,
                      );
                    }

                    var userData = snapshot.data;
                    String _imageUrl = url.data;
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      List books = userData['audio_read'];
                      if (books == null) {
                        return Loading(
                          size: 15,
                        );
                        //this
                      }
                      return Scaffold(
                        body: Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Transform.translate(
                              offset: Offset(screenWidth * 0.4, 10),
                              child: Transform.rotate(
                                angle: -0.1,
                                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                  logo,
                                  height: logoHeight,
                                  color: logoTintColor,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SingleChildScrollView(
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 60,
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 16.0),
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: <Widget>[
//
                                        createFirstNameHeader(
                                            user, ref, userData),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              right: 16.0, bottom: 16, top: 16),
                                          child: Material(
                                            elevation: 4,
                                            borderRadius:
                                                const BorderRadius.all(
                                                    Radius.circular(12)),
                                            child: Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                  left: 16.0,
                                                  right: 16.0,
                                                  top: 16.0,
                                                  bottom: 32.0),
                                              child: Column(
                                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  Row(
                                                    children: <Widget>[
                                                      Text(
                                                        "TOTAL TALES PLAYED",
                                                        style:
                                                            hoursPlayedLabelTextStyle,
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                  SizedBox(
                                                    height: 4,
                                                  ),
                                                  Text(
                                                    "${books.length.toString()} ${books.length > 1 ? "Tales" : "Tale"}",
                                                    style: hoursPlayedTextStyle
                                                        .copyWith(
                                                            color: Color(
                                                                0xff5E17EB)),
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        ContentHeadingWidget(
                                            heading: "Continue listening"),
                                        for (var i = books.length - 1;
                                            i >= 0;
                                            i--)
                                          books.length > 0
                                              ? Slidable(
                                                  actionExtentRatio: 0.25,
                                                  actionPane:
                                                      SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
                                                  secondaryActions: <Widget>[
                                                    IconSlideAction(
                                                        caption: 'Delete',
                                                        color: Colors.red,
                                                        icon: Icons.delete,
                                                        onTap: () => {
                                                              _deletePressed(
                                                                  user,
                                                                  books.elementAt(
                                                                          i)[
                                                                      'audio_id']),
                                                            }),
                                                  ],
                                                  child: LastReadBook(
                                                      audioId: books.elementAt(
                                                          i)['audio_id'],
                                                      audio_index: int.parse(
                                                          books.elementAt(i)[
                                                              'audio_index']),
                                                      audioSeek: books.elementAt(
                                                          i)['audio_seek'],
                                                      total: books.elementAt(
                                                          i)['total'],
                                                      progress: int.parse(books.elementAt(i)['audio_index']) /
                                                          books.elementAt(
                                                              i)["totalIndex"],
                                                      description:
                                                          "${books.elementAt(i)["audio_index"]} of ${books.elementAt(i)["totalIndex"]} episodes",
                                                      image: books
                                                          .elementAt(i)['image']),
                                                )
                                              : Loading(
                                                  size: 15,
                                                ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Loading(
                        size: 15,
                      );
                    }
                  });
            } else {
              return Loading(
                size: 15,
              );
            }
          }),
    );
  }

  Padding createFirstNameHeader(
      User user, StorageService ref, DocumentSnapshot userData) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 16.0,
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          createProfileImage(user, ref),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
            child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                children: [
                  TextSpan(
                    text: 'Hello',
                    style: userNameTextStyle,
                  ),
                  TextSpan(text: '\n'),
                  TextSpan(
                      text: userData['firstname'], style: userNameTextStyle),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  createProfileImage(User user, StorageService ref) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection("Users")
            .document(user.uid)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
//            return Center(
//              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
//            );
            return Loading(
              size: 15,
            );
          }

          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Loading(
              size: 15,
            );
          }

          print(snapshot.data.data);
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () async {
              if (user.uid != HomeScreen.defaultUID) {
                dynamic imageFromUser = await ref.getImage();
                await ref.addImageToFirebase(user.uid, imageFromUser);
              } else {
                createAccountDialouge(context);
              }
            },
            child: RoundedImageWidget(
                imagePath: snapshot.data["profile_image"],
                icon: Icons.photo_camera,
                showIcon: true),
          );
        });
  }

  createAccountDialouge(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      child: CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: Text('Avid Tale Would Like to Enable Full Access'),
        content: Text('Creating an account will enable access to this feature'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            child: Text('Cancel'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            child: Text('Register'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return RegisterScreen();
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _deletePressed(user, bookId) async {
    DatabaseService userService = DatabaseService(uid: user.uid);

    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
        await Firestore.instance.collection("Users").document(user.uid).get();
    var data = documentSnapshot.data["audio_read"];

    data.retainWhere((element) => element["audio_id"] != bookId);
    await userService.updateUserData({'audio_read': FieldValue.delete()});
    await userService
        .updateUserData({'audio_read': FieldValue.arrayUnion(data)});
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to share your code.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore okay sharing here

Comment: @ChristopherMoore it is the code of the menu screen which is flickering sir

Comment: i have attached a gif of the flicking screen as well, kindly look @ChristopherMoore

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you delete an item, it triggers a new event in the `Stream`. As the `Stream` is retrieving/processing the new data it goes into this `if` block of code as the `connectionState` changes to `waiting`:

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
  return Loading(
    size: 15,
  );
}
```

Simply removing this block of code will should stop the "flickering". You may need to include other checks of data availability if necessary for your application.

Comment: what about when i come to that menu? it flicks at that time too @Christopher Moore

Comment: That can't really be considered a flicker. Something has to be shown on the screen while the data is loading. In your case it is loading very quickly, but that may not always be the case.

Comment: i have attached a new gif please see it, when i click on fav(heart) menu it doesnt flick anytime, it is complety smooth but the side menu flicks everytime, i want it to be smooth as well, please help i am so fed up of it, i removed that part of code but it still happens

Comment: As I already said this cannot be considered a flicker. You have to show something while the data is being loaded. If you don't want to show a loading indicator, just change it to an empty container.

Comment: okay i accept the data is being loaded, but when we click on fav(heart) button then why it is not flicking although the data is loading there as well. It doesnt flick a fraction of sec even, this is my question.

Comment: Your code is a bit messy and it's difficult to find where the code for the heart icon button is.

Comment: this is the code of menu page( which is called profile screen) , the heart icon button is on home screen, do you want me to post code of home screen?